# Embed Google Calendar via iFrame in UIWebView into iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

I have attempted to embed a calendar from Google Calendar for public viewing only. I do not have any errors, but nothing loads whenever I run my app. What am I doing wrong that the calendar will not load whenever requested?

```
NSString *iframe = @"<iframe src=\"https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=360&amp;wkst=1&amp;hl=en&amp;bgcolor=%23@c0000&amp;src=chipbeck4670%40gmail.com&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York\" style=\" border-width:0 \" width=\"320\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe>";

HTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY>%@</BODY></HTML>", iframe];

[cal loadHTMLString:HTML baseURL:nil];
```

Thanks!

Comment: My attempt to go to the URL the webview generates resulted in me seeing an error: "Mode parameter (bgcolor) is invalid. It should be a hex color such as #FF0000".  Are you passing in the correct bgcolor / color?  They don't quite look like correct hex values.

Comment: Also when I loaded that iframe in a simple http document, my console was telling me: "Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&showPrint=0&showTabs=0&sh…@c0000&src=chipbeck4670%40gmail.com&color=%232952A3&ctz=America%2FNew_York' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. "